# Concatenate a string and an integer and assign it to a new column

Tags: awk

Code(AWK script):

```
for(i=0; i<numColumns; ++i){

$(NF+i)="group" #This will print group, but I want to print 
#group1, group2, group3 and so on...
#In other words, i want something like $(NF+i)="group".$i so that 
#the output is group1, group2....

    }
```

I am adding these words in new columns, hence the (NF+i).

my question is how to concatenate so I can print group1, group2 and so on.
I can do that with the print command but I want to assign that to column NF+i.

Comment: Could you use a `group` array with numeric indices instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try: (print statement omitted)

```
for(i=0; i<numColumns; ++i){

$(NF+i)="group " i


    }
```

Comment: Why do i get increasing spaces after each print? My code is `$(NF+i)="group"i` and prints like `group1 group2  group3` and so on but with one more space after each print